# Python references

Tags: python, list, reference

after the for loop arrays gets the values from tmp1. How can i store values for later use?

```
def getCardRank(self, arrays, straight = False):
  print arrays

  tmp1 = arrays[:]  
  tmp2 = {i: arrays[i] for i in range(0, len(arrays))}

  print tmp1

  for array in tmp1:
    for card in array:
      i = array.index(card)
      mod = card % 13

      if (mod == 0 and False != straight):
        card = 0 if sum(array) == 27 else 13
      else:
        card = 13 if mod == 0 else mod
        array[i] = card

  print tmp1
  print tmp2
```

that gives me:

```
[[44, 43, 42, 41, 40], [37, 36, 35, 34, 33], [17, 16, 15, 14, 26]]

[[44, 43, 42, 41, 40], [37, 36, 35, 34, 33], [17, 16, 15, 14, 26]]

{0: [44, 43, 42, 41, 40], 1: [37, 36, 35, 34, 33], 2: [17, 16, 15, 14, 26]}

[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [11, 10, 9, 8, 7], [4, 3, 2, 1, 13]]

{0: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 1: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7], 2: [4, 3, 2, 1, 13]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on the question, but I'll assume that you want `print(tmp1)` to always `print [44, 43, 42]...`etc instead of `[5, 4, 3]`.

The problem with the assignment `tmp1 = arrays[:]` is that if you create a copy of a list to iterate over using slice notation, [the original list is changed](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

In order to store the original array in tmp1, a rather inefficient solution would be to create a tuple `tmp1` and iterate over arrays appending each element to `tmp1`. Another would be, as previously suggested, to pickle your data structures.

However, it looks like the real solution is to change how you're thinking about storing `tmp1` - consider that if you need to retain the original arrays after calling `getCardRank`, you probably want to think of it as part of the object that `self` refers to in the function's signature. Therefore, you should store the original copy of arrays in a member variable (`self.foo = [array for array in arrays]`).

As a side note, it makes your code somewhat more difficult to read when you use inline conditionals.

Comment: I made a tuple and then converted back to a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) your array data structures to persist them into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function signature has a `self` in it, I assume this function is a member function of some object.

In that case, you can save values as member variables in order for them to persist through the life of the instantiated object.

For instance:

```
def doSomething(self):
  self.someValue = 2
```

`self.someValue` will persist after doSomething() exits, and it will persist until the calling object is deleted.